# In Azure Active directory user disable option is there?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

How to disable users in Windows active directory.we are using Microsoft Azure.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To disable a user you would use the graph API. To do this, call  update on the user with the PATCH HTTP method:

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version
```

And include in the body:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": false
}
```

Please see this for ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser

/ip

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Windows Server AD, just click the user and disable using Active Directory User and Computers.

If you are using Azure Active Directory, click user, navigate to profile and block user sign in and access in settings.

[image]

Comment: Just beware - it can take several minutes before the user is displayed as "Account enabled" = "No" in the All Users summary list.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the information provided above, The user can be either synced or In-cloud within the Azure Active Directory created natively within the Azure AD. If the user is synced. The user's attribute called account enabled is the one which defines whether the user is enabled or disabled. A disabled user is barred from logon to the Azure portal / any service federated with user's related Azure AD. On the new Azure portal the in-cloud user can be disabled as below.

[image: User Setting - Block sign-in]

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Entra ID (Sept 2023 for relevance), going to Users, then selecting a user account presents the dialog below.  Click edit and disable the account:

[image]