# Disable office365 mailbox using graph api

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to disable mailbox using logic apps.I have choosen to use graph api. I searched online and ended up using [disabledPlans](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_assignlicense).

But I have a requirement where I have to use logic apps and i cannot hardcode the skuIds and dont know what license is added to the user.I am able to get licenses assinged to user using getUser in beta version of graph api. But there is no relation between license of product and its plans. This is making my job tedious.
   Power shell has a command called Disable-Mailbox. But ,I am unable to find such api in graph api. Can any one let me know if disabling plans is right way or is there any other way I can disable mail box using Logic apps or graph api. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Azure Active directory user disable option is there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472796/in-azure-active-directory-user-disable-option-is-there)

Comment: Kevin,
 I need to disable mail box, but not the complete account of the user. :)

Comment: As far as I know the only way to explictly disable a mailbox is to use powershell, disabling the plan in the Graph API could lead to deprovisioning of the mailbox and loss of data - but I can't find documentation that states what the behavior is and I haven't tested it myself. Have you tried it? That would be a good starting point