# How can I disable a user from an Azure Active Directory programatically with C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to disable an user from the azure active directive using c# code.
can anyone me help on this?

Comment: You cannot make any change in Active directory. That's administrator's job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Azure Active directory user disable option is there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472796/in-azure-active-directory-user-disable-option-is-there)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at how you can [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0).

> Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources. After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

It has an [Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) method you can use to set the `accountEnabled` property of the user to *false*.

> **true** if the account is enabled; otherwise, **false**. This property is required when a user is created. Supports $filter.